# Unable to retrieve message from background in popup of chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to communicate between the popup.js file and the background.js file for a chrome extension. However when retrieving information using the chrome storage, the execution of the callback no longer is received by the client (popup.js)

within the background.js file.

```
function getTotals(callback){
  chrome.storage.sync.get(LMSCats, function(data){
    callback({"results": data}); // does not work
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // sendResponse({"message": "hi"}); //works
    getTotals(sendResponse);
  }
}
```

Within the popup.js referenced from the popup.html file

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: "total"}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

I am not sure if I'm missing something from the documentation so any help will be appreciated.
I came across [chrome extension onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) however I wasn't sure if this is related or how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read properly

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // sendResponse({"message": "hi"}); //works
    getTotals(sendResponse);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Solved the problem:

According to the documentation

> This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, unless
>   you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a
>   response asynchronously (this will keep the message channel open to
>   the other end until sendResponse is called).

Hope this helps someone else in the future.